# Violação de restrição de multiplicidade

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Alguém já se deparou com esse erro em uma aplicação asp.net mvc?

> Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'.
>
> Ocorreu uma violação de restrição de multiplicidade de relação: uma EntityReference não pode ter mais de um objeto relacionado, mas a consulta retornou mais de um objeto relacionado. Esse é um erro irrecuperável.

Após bom período funcionando normalmente a aplicação passou a dar erro ao tentar chamar uma lista de dados. Rodando a aplicação recebo esse erro.

Comment: Pelo enunciado, parece fazer referência a mais de um objeto. Não sei em que momento está dando esse erro, deverias dar mais detalhes. Existe um padrão de projeto, chamado Singleton, não sei se vem ao caso, mas em situações onde deveríamos ter apenas uma única e somente uma instância, esse padrão é o ideal. Dê uma olhada nele e veja como implementá-lo, é a coisa mais simples do planeta.Agora dê mais informações, mostre o que você já fez para podermos ajudá-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Verifique o *Attribute* `[Table]` dos seus *Models*. Verifique se não tem algum repetido:

```
[Table("Cidades")]
public class Cidade { ... }
```

Comment: Obrigado Cigano! Acabei descobrindo que inseriram um dado que já havia no banco e na hora da minha consulta o programou reclamou na hora de exibir o registro. O erro identificava no meu caso não um atributo repetido no model, mas um registro duplicado numa coluna/view do model.